# How to write an element of a nested list whose index is given by the elements of another list

Tags: list-manipulation

This is purely a list manipulation question. I have a simple non-nested list of positive integers of length `m` say (where `m` could be large):

```
t={t1,...,tm}
```

I have another nested list  `s` which is `m` times nested so `s` represents a rank `m` tensor e.g. when `m=2`,  `s` represents a matrix. How do I write the following

```
s[[t1]]...[[tm]]
```

in simple closed form (i.e. without ellipses)? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Should be `s[[t]]`.

Comment: So you mean that `s` has `m` indices, right? So basically you want `s[[t1, t2, t3, ..., tm]]` if I understand correctly. That could be achieved by `s[[Sequence @@ t]]` or `Extract[s, t]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple concrete example with a rank-3 tensor:

```
In[19]:= s = RandomReal[1, {5, 6, 7}];
Dimensions[s]
TensorRank[s]

Out[20]= {5, 6, 7}

Out[21]= 3
```

Extracting the element at position `{3, 1, 2}` can be done by repeatedly taking a `Part` (`[[...]]`) each level down, but it's easier to just use a single `Part` spec:

```
In[35]:= s[[3]][[1]][[2]]
s[[3, 1, 2]]

Out[35]= 0.350807

Out[36]= 0.350807
```

If you have the position stored in a variable, you can use `Sequence` to splice it into the `Part` brackets or you can use extract:

```
In[26]:= t = {3, 1, 2};
s[[Sequence @@ t]]
Extract[s, t]

Out[27]= 0.350807

Out[28]= 0.350807
```

If you really want to use repeated parts (which is probably not a good idea, but just for purposes of illustration), you can use `Fold`, to repeatedly extract the next level of the tensor. This is equivalent to `s[[3]][[1]][[2]]`:

```
In[32]:= Fold[#1[[#2]] &, s, t]

Out[32]= 0.350807
```